# A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid -- Safari only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, safari

I have an asp.net mvc 2 project with the typical xss protection

`<%=Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>` inside each form and `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` on each Post action.

This works as expected in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

But I get the following error in Safari (v 5.1.7).

> System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException:  A required anti-forgery
>   token was not supplied or was invalid.

I see the reason for the exception is the `RequestValidationToken` cookie that is created has an incorrect expiration date of `Mon, 01 Jan 2001`, while in the other browsers is is correctly set to `Session`.

**How can I make Safari stop assigning a bogus expiration date to my Anti-Forgery cookie?**

Comment: I also experience this problem but cannot find anything about this. Do you already have a solution?

Comment: No I haven't found a solution.  Please let me know if you come up with something!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by removing 'negotiate' from the list of authentication providers in IIS.

Similar to this issue with safari:

[Windows Authentication issue with Safari 5.x in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817452/windows-authentication-issue-with-safari-5-x-in-windows-7)