# MVC 3 - A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid - Safari IOS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, antiforgerytoken, request-validation

I have this form in asp MVC 3

```
<form action="/account/changeemail" id="form_changeemail" method="post">
    <%=Html.AntiForgeryToken()%>
    <input  type="email" name="email" id="email" class="required email" />
    <button class="green button" type="submit" id="changeemail">Change</button>
</form>
```

And this action

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ChangeEmail(string email)
{

}
```

And on Safari on IOS this always gives me

**A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid**

This is the user agent of the browser

**Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11B511 Safari/9537.53**

I've looked at the cookies, and the one for the request validation token is set to 1st of January 2001.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834036/a-required-anti-forgery-token-was-not-supplied-or-was-invalid-safari-only

Comment: I don't use windows authentication :) Any other ideas ?

Comment: Found the problem: I was using jquery 1.4.2 on that page (for some unknown reason :D) and that was screwing it up

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me after selecting.

Go to Safari `Settings >> Preferences... >> Privacy tab`

1. Click Remove all website data
2. Select Block cookies as Never

Comment: While this may work, it really does not address the real world situation as most user's do not disable this setting. Safari's conservative cookie policy does not allow cookie-creation from 3rd party domains until a user click is made. The first click, therefore, on form for instance, will always return said error.